# merge/join dataframes with not fully matching columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

My data consist of an id and yearly values for each id. I collect the values for a lot of persons in separate dataframes, one for each person at a time.

an example of one id is in the dataframe df1

```
id y2010 y2011 y2012 y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017
abc  4     6     9     11    12    13    10    9
```

however the next id def have data from 1985 to 2017 (y1985 to y2017) in df2

Now I want to join these two dataframes df1 and df2 in such a way that the resulting dataframe df3

```
id y1985 y1986 .... y2013 y2014 y2015 y2016 y2017
abc  .     .          11    12    13    10    9    
def  12    17         50    75    80   100  110
```

consist of all variables (columns) together in df1 and df2, but in a way that variables both in df1 and df2 is merged. if the column does not exist in df2 then that variable should be set to NA, and if the column does not exist in df1 it will be created.

Any ideas how to do it?

Tx to Moody_Mudskipper who pointed me to rbindlist

```
require(data.table)
df3 <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE)
```

is the solution

Comment: No it is as I see it different. I want to do a left outer join at the same time as a right outer join

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I have changed the reference of duplicate post based on your suggestion.

Comment: Tx Moody_Mudskipper. I just followed your originate link to rbindlist (after your edit it is now broken). It worked as described above in my originate post.